# gRPC, C#, ORM. Как с помощью сервиса gRPC вернуть из бд коллекцию с 2мя параметрами(и более) и передать клиенту?

Tags: c#, orm, grpc

Изучаю gRPC. Хочу у клиента отобразить список карт клиента, который имеет два параметра: наименование карты (accounts_name ), номер карты (accounts_num).

```
//фрагмент кода greet.proto
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "FSSGrpcService";
package greet;

service Greeter {
  rpc GetClientCardList (FindClientByPhone) returns (stream Card);
}

message FindClientByPhone {
  string phone = 1;
}
message Card {
  string accounts_name = 1;
  string accounts_num = 2;
}
```

Класс для поиска клиента в базе данных. В методе GetCardList, который должен вернуть список Card с двумя параметрами, внутри цикла foreach ошибка, C# не понимает, что в greet.proto Card принимает два параметра

```
public class DataBaseRequest
{
    private readonly DataBaseContext _db;
    public DataBaseRequest(DataBaseContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    //метод, чтобы найти клиента по номеру телефона
    public Client FindClientByPhone(string phone)
    {
        return _db.clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.client_cellnum == phone);
    }
    //метод, который должен вернуть список Card с двумя параметрами. Внутри цикла foreach ошибка, C# не понимает, что в greet.proto Card принимает два параметра
    public List<Card> GetCardList(string phone)
    {
        var db = new DataBaseContext();
        var users = db.clients.Join(db.accounts,
            c => c.client_id, 
            a => a.accounts_clientid, 
            (c, a) => new 
            {
                CellNum = c.client_cellnum,
                AccountName = a.accounts_name,
                AccountNum = a.accounts_num
            }).Where(x => x.CellNum == phone.ToString()).OrderBy(x => x.AccountNum);
        List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            cards.Add(new Card(u.AccountName, u.AccountNum)); //Ошибка  CS1729  "Card" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 2.
        }
    return cards;
    }
}
```

Класс GreeterService, который представляет реализацию сервиса gPRC на языке C#.

Метод GetClientCardNameList выдает ошибку CS0115: не найден метод, пригодный для переопределения.

Также в цикле foreach не знаю как правильно оформить поток ответа. Ошибка CS0200    Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору "Card.AccountName", тоже самое и для "Card.AccountNum"

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override async Task GetClientCardList(FindClientByPhone request, IServerStreamWriter<Card> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)  //Ошибка  CS0115: не найден метод, пригодный для переопределения.

    {
        var db = new DataBaseContext();
        var service = new DataBaseRequest(db);
        List<Card> ls = new List<Card>();
        ls.AddRange(service.GetCardList(request.Phone));

        foreach (var item in ls)
        {
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(new Card{ AccountName = item.AccountName, AccountNum = item.AccountNum });  //Ошибка    CS0200  Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору "Card.AccountName". тоже самое для и "Card.AccountNum"
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно ли вообще с помощью gRPC передать в объекте потока ответа несколько параметров, чтобы клиент смог вывести в ответ как на следующей картинке?
В блоке счета выведен наименование и номер карты (Карточный, 40817810310009035474). В данном случае я сделал костыль, каждый параметр получал с помощью двух запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Засунуть нужные значения не в конструктор, а в свойства? `var card = new Card { Foo = 1, Bar = 2 }`. Вообще посмотрите, что вам сгенерировалось в Card.

Comment: Я бы использовал `repeated field` - "массив значений" вместо `stream` - "потока ответов"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OwDafuq вы направили меня в нужное направление. Решил свой вопрос следующим образом:
в методе GetCardList внутри цикла создал новый экземпляр Card с конструктором и передавал его в List

```
public List<Card> GetCardList(string phone)
{
    var db = new DataBaseContext();
    var users = db.clients.Join(db.accounts,
        c => c.client_id,
        a => a.accounts_clientid, 
        (c, a) => new
        {
            CellNum = c.client_cellnum,
            AccountName = a.accounts_name,
            AccountNum = a.accounts_num
        }).Where(x => x.CellNum == phone.ToString()).OrderBy(x => x.AccountNum);
    List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
    foreach (var u in users)
    {
        Card card = new Card()
        { 
            AccountsName = u.AccountName, 
            AccountsNum = u.AccountNum 
        };
        cards.Add(card);
    }
    return cards;
}
```